# m Smallest values from upper triangular matrix with their indices as a list of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, min

I have a np.ndarray as follows:

```
[[ inf   1.   3.   2.   1.]
 [ inf  inf   2.   3.   2.]
 [ inf  inf  inf   5.   4.]
 [ inf  inf  inf  inf   1.]
 [ inf  inf  inf  inf  inf]]
```

Is there a way to get the indices and values of the m smallest items in that nd array? So, if I wanted the 4 smallest it would be

```
[(0,1,1),(0,4,1),(3,4,1),(0,3,2)]
```

where (row,col,val) is the notation above.

If there are multiple values then one of them is just randomly chosen. For instance, there were 3 ones and then next smallest is a value 2 but (0,3,2), (1,2,2),(1,4,2) were all possible choices.

Essentially, Can I extract the k smallest values in that format from the upper triangular matrix efficiently (the matrix is much larger than the example above). I tried flattening it, using square form, nsmallest, but am having trouble getting the indices and values to align. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577375/have-numpy-argsort-return-an-array-of-2d-indices
`np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(tri.ravel()), arr.shape))`
All that's left is zipping the values on.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10337643/149076 ... though it's finding the largest K items rather than the smallest.

Another, fairly crude, approach would be to use numpy.ndenumerate() to generate a flat list of co-ordinates and values which you feed into a heap before taking the heapq.nsmallest() items.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: yes just tried yours, nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an `Inf` filled array -

```
r,c = np.unravel_index(a.ravel().argsort()[:4], a.shape)
out = zip(r,c,a[r,c])
```

For performance, consider using `np.argpartition`. So, replace `a.ravel().argsort()[:4]` with `np.argpartition(a.ravel(), range(4))[:4]`.

Sample run -

```
In [285]: a
Out[285]: 
array([[ inf,   1.,   3.,   2.,   1.],
       [ inf,  inf,   2.,   3.,   2.],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,   5.,   4.],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,   1.],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf]])

In [286]: out
Out[286]: [(0, 1, 1.0), (0, 4, 1.0), (3, 4, 1.0), (0, 3, 2.0)]
```

---

For a generic case -

```
R,C = np.triu_indices(a.shape[1],1)
idx = a[R,C].argsort()[:4]
r,c = R[idx], C[idx]
out = zip(r,c,a[r,c])
```

Sample run -

```
In [351]: a
Out[351]: 
array([[ 68.,  67.,  81.,  23.,  16.],
       [ 84.,  83.,  20.,  66.,  48.],
       [ 58.,  72.,  98.,  63.,  30.],
       [ 61.,  40.,   1.,  86.,  22.],
       [ 29.,  95.,  38.,  22.,  95.]])
In [352]: out
Out[352]: [(0, 4, 16.0), (1, 2, 20.0), (3, 4, 22.0), (0, 3, 23.0)]
```

For performance, consider using `np.argpartition`. So, replace `a[R,C].argsort()[:4]` with `np.argpartition(a[R,C], range(4))[:4]`.

Comment: `list(zip(...))` in python3

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(4,4)
tuples = [(ix,iy, a[ix,iy]) for ix, row in enumerate(a) for iy, i in enumerate(row)]
sorted(tuples,key=lambda x: x[2])[:10]
```

Where k=10 (`[:10]`) from your question.

If you only want the upper triangular elements you can add a condition to the list comprehension:

```
a = np.random.rand(4,4)
tuples = [(ix,iy, a[ix,iy]) for ix, row in enumerate(a) for iy, i in enumerate(row) if ix<=iy]
sorted(tuples,key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If my *np.array()* is *n* I could get the n smallest values from it by flattening it (with *np.ndenumerate()), and using the *heapq* module's *.heapify()* and *.smallest()* methods like so:

```
#!python
flattened = [(y,x) for x,y in np.ndenumerate(n)]
# tuples reversed for natural sorting on values rather than co-ords
heapq.heapify(flattened)
results = heapq.nsmallest(4, flattened)
```

But this will use plenty of extra memory and will extract the data and co-ordinates out of Numpy's efficient arrays into Python's native lists.  So there's probably much better ways to do it more natively in Python.

Comment: I tried this but if the matrix is huge its really slow because of the loop

Comment: Exactly as I said,  Thus my other suggestion, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6910715/149076 ... bottleneck is a compiled extension to Numpy for partial sorting.