# Argsorting values in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists `A` of length `m`. Every list of `A` contains positive numbers from `{1, 2, ..., n}`. The following is an example, where `m = 3` and `n = 4`.

```
A = [[1, 1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 4]]
```

I represent every number `x` in `A` as a pair `(i, j)` where `A[i][j] = x`. I would like to sort the numbers in `A` in non-decreasing order; breaking ties by lowest first index. That is, if `A[i1][j1] == A[i2][j2]`, then `(i1, j1)` comes before `(i2, j2)` iff `i1 <= i2`.

In the example, I would like to return the pairs:

```
(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 3)
```

which represents the sorted numbers

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4
```

What I did is a naive approach that works as follows:

- First I sort every list in `A`.
- Then I iterate the numbers in `{1, 2, ..., n}` and the list `A` and add the pairs.

Code:

```
for i in range(m): 
    A[i].sort()
S = []
for x in range(1, n+1):
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            if A[i][j] == x:
                S.append((i, j))
```

I think this approach is not good. Can we do better?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### `list.sort`

You can generate a list of indexes and then call `list.sort` with a `key`:

```
B = [(i, j) for i, x in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(x)]
B.sort(key=lambda ix: A[ix[0]][ix[1]])
```

```
print(B)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Note that on python-2.x where iterable unpacking in functions is supported, you can simplify the `sort` call a bit:

```
B.sort(key=lambda (i, j): A[i][j])
```

---

#### `sorted`

This is an alternative to the version above, and generates *two* lists (one in memory which `sorted` then works on, to return another copy).

```
B = sorted([
       (i, j) for i, x in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(x)
    ], 
    key=lambda ix: A[ix[0]][ix[1]]
)

print(B)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 3)]
```

---

#### Performance

On popular demand, adding some timings and a plot.

[image]

From the graph, we see that calling `list.sort` is more efficient than `sorted`. This is because `list.sort` performs an in-place sort, so there is no time/space overhead from creating a copy of the data which `sorted` has.

**Functions**

```
def cs1(A):
    B = [(i, j) for i, x in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(x)]
    B.sort(key=lambda ix: A[ix[0]][ix[1]]) 

    return B

def cs2(A):
    return sorted([
           (i, j) for i, x in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(x)
        ], 
        key=lambda ix: A[ix[0]][ix[1]]
    )

def rorydaulton(A):

    triplets = [(x, i, j) for i, row in enumerate(A) for j, x in enumerate(row)]
    pairs = [(i, j) for x, i, j in sorted(triplets)]

    return pairs

def jpp(A):
    def _create_array(data):
        lens = np.array([len(i) for i in data])
        mask = np.arange(lens.max()) < lens[:,None]
        out = np.full(mask.shape, max(map(max, data))+1, dtype=int)  # Pad with max_value + 1
        out[mask] = np.concatenate(data)
        return out

    def _apply_argsort(arr):
        return np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(arr.ravel()), arr.shape))[0]

    return _apply_argsort(_create_array(A))[:sum(map(len, A))]

def agngazer(A):
    idx = np.argsort(np.fromiter(chain(*A), dtype=np.int))
    return np.array(
       tuple((i, j) for i, r in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(r))
    )[idx]
```

**Performance Benchmarking Code**

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['cs1', 'cs2', 'rorydaulton', 'jpp', 'agngazer'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000],
       dtype=float
)

for f in res.index: 
    for c in res.columns:
        l = [[1, 1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 4]] * c
        stmt = '{}(l)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import l, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=30)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True) 
ax.set_xlabel("N"); 
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)");

plt.show();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171892/discussion-on-answer-by-coldspeed-argsorting-values-in-a-list-of-lists).

Answer (score 18):

You could make *triplets* of `(x, i, j)`, sort those triplets, then extract the indices `(i, j)`. That works because the triplets contain all the information needed for the sorting and for inclusion in the final list, in the order needed for the sorting. (This is called the "Decorate-Sort-Undecorate" idiom, related to the Schwartzian transform--Hat-tip to @Morgen for the name and generalization and the motivation for me to explain the generality of this technique.) This could be combined into a single statement but I split it up here for clarity.

```
A = [[1, 1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 4]]

triplets = [(x, i, j) for i, row in enumerate(A) for j, x in enumerate(row)]
pairs = [(i, j) for x, i, j in sorted(triplets)]
print(pairs)
```

Here is the printed result:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (0, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: This looks like a specific example of a https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform (also known as decorate-sort-undecorate), a mention of which may make your answer more generally applicable

Comment: @Morgen: Thanks for the added information--I did not know the name or the particular transform. If I understand your article correctly, I did not use the transform itself but rather the "Decorate-Sort-Undecorate" idiom which is similar. I first thought of that idiom in the group theory context, not in computer science, and used it in my solution of the Rubik's Cube back in the early 80's. (My idea of "sort" was more general, not quite sorting.)

Comment: Fair point. I should probably find an article on decorate-sort-undecorate, I mostly use that one because it's easy to remember were to find it

Answer (score 3):

Just because @jpp is having fun:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
def agn(A):
    idx = np.argsort(np.fromiter(chain(*A), dtype=np.int))
    return np.array(tuple((i, j) for i, r in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(r)))[idx]
```

### Timing Tests:

#### Test 1:

Comparison against fastest method from @coldspeed:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: print(np.__version__)
1.13.3

In [3]: from itertools import chain

In [4]: import sys

In [5]: print(sys.version)
3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 12 2018, 16:25:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]

In [6]: A = [[1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 4]] * 10000

In [7]: %timeit np.array(tuple((i, j) for i, r in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(r)))[np.argsort(np.fromit
   ...: er(chain(*A), dtype=np.int))]
89.4 ms ± 718 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit B = [(i, j) for i, x in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(x)]; B.sort(key=lambda ix: A[ix[0]]
   ...: [ix[1]])
93.5 ms ± 1.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Test 2a:

This test uses one randomly generated large array `A` (each sublist is sorted because this is how OP list appears to be):

```
In [20]: A = [sorted([random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(random.randint(1,1000))]) for _ in range(10000)]

In [21]: def agn(A):
    ...:     idx = np.argsort(np.fromiter(chain(*A), dtype=np.int))
    ...:     return np.array(tuple((i, j) for i, r in enumerate(A) for j, _ in enumerate(r)))[idx]
    ...:     

In [22]: %timeit agn(A)
3.1 s ± 62.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [23]: %timeit cs1(A)
3.2 s ± 89.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### Test 2.b

Similar to test 2.b but with an unsorted array `A`:

```
In [25]: A = [[random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(random.randint(1,1000))] for _ in range(10000)]

In [26]: %timeit cs1(A)
4.24 s ± 215 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [27]: %timeit agn(A)
3.44 s ± 49.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for timing tests! I also added my own tests (with a slightly different `A`) to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here's a method via 3rd party library `numpy`. Performance is around ~10% slower than @coldspeed's solution due to the expensive padding step.

**Credits**: For this solution, I have adapted @Divakar's [array-from-jagged-list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043366/9209546) recipe, and copied verbatim @AshwiniChaudhary's [multi-dimension argsort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577520/9209546) solution.

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 4]]

def create_array(data):

    """Convert jagged list to numpy array; pad with max_value + 1"""

    lens = np.array([len(i) for i in data])
    mask = np.arange(lens.max()) < lens[:,None]
    out = np.full(mask.shape, max(map(max, data))+1, dtype=int)  # Pad with max_value + 1
    out[mask] = np.concatenate(data)
    return out

def apply_argsort(arr):

    """Flatten, argsort, extract indices, then stack into a single array"""

    return np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(arr.ravel()), arr.shape))[0]

# limit only to number of elements in A
res = apply_argsort(create_array(A))[:sum(map(len, A))]

print(res)

[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [1 1]
 [2 2]
 [0 2]
 [2 3]]
```