# Sort a 2-D matrix elements from largest to smallest, tracking ij indices too

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

Given an upper triangular matrix (or lower triangular)

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [0, 4, 5],
              [0, 0, 6]]
             )
```

I would like to sort its values from largest to smallest, keeping track of the ij indices, so for instance in this matrix I would want something like

```
6, (2,2)
5, (1,2)
4, (1,1)
3, (0,2)
2, (0,1)
1, (0,0)
```

This simple example uses a matrix with integers, but it should handle floats as well as arbitrarily large matrices, generally between 10x10 and 40x40. Speed is not very important, it is a one time operation. Also, it need not be upper or lower, the matrix is symmetrical, so I can simply fill in the opposite triangle if that is easier.

I have tried `np.argsort()` but that just gives

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

which is to say, it sorts each row independently. This doesn't help much since I don't want a list of the largest elements in each row, it could be that one row has all of the largest values.

Comment: `np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(-A.ravel()), (3, 3)))` ? source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577520/12502959

Comment: @python_user I think that works, it orders it in reverse, but that isn't a big deal

Comment: I just edited it to order in the way you want

Comment: @python_user I guess you might as well post this one-liner as an answer.

Comment: @Stef other than the making the array negative, I did not really change anything from the source, if anything, this can be a dupe of that, but my numpy skills are not good enough to confidently mark it a dupe

Comment: @python_user So you don't want to "claim credit" by making it your answer, which is very honest of you; still, comments tend to disappear, and this answers the question. If anyone with a similar question finds this page in the future because of a search engine, and it is neither marked as a duplicate nor answered, they'll be disappointed. Note that you can tick the "community answer" box when writing an answer if you really don't want credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577520/12502959), (provided you negate your array) to perform a "2d argsort".

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 4, 5], [0, 0, 6]])

>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 6]])

>>> np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(-A.ravel()), (3, 3)))
array([[[2, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [2, 1]]], dtype=int64)
```

PS : If any user who is confident of their numpy skills feel this should be a dupe do mark it, in the mean time this will be a "Community Wiki" as suggested by [Stef in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68922325/sort-a-2-d-matrix-elements-from-largest-to-smallest-tracking-ij-indices-too?noredirect=1#comment121808577_68922325).